# SVG to Image Using SVGSalamander not rendering SVG correctly

Tags: java, image, svg, converters, svg-salamander

I have worked for SVG image rendering for iText PDF document. 
to do this i used SVGSalamander for convert SVG to image format. 
it works fine but it has a strange behavior that some of the SVG images are not rendering correctly while some are doing. those wrongly rendered svg are not aligned with the real image. 
I tried but i couldn't figure out why its happening only for some images.

Really appreciate if someone help me to resolve this.

Java Code:

```
private static Image createSVGImage(PdfWriter pdfWriter, String imageEntry) throws BadElementException {
        Image image = null;

        Graphics2D g2dgraphics =null;
        PdfTemplate template = null;
        try{
            SVGDiagram diagram = SVGCache.getSVGUniverse().getDiagram( new java.io.File( imageEntry ).toURI() );
            template = pdfWriter.getDirectContent().createTemplate( diagram.getWidth(), diagram.getHeight());
            diagram.setIgnoringClipHeuristic(true);
             g2dgraphics= new PdfGraphics2D(template, diagram.getWidth(), diagram.getHeight());
        diagram.render(g2dgraphics);
    }catch( Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if( g2dgraphics != null ){
            g2dgraphics.dispose();
          image = Image.getInstance(template);

        }
        g2dgraphics.dispose();
    }

    return image;
}
```

SVG xml code that its not align

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M19,16a46,46 0,1,0 62,0l-8,8a34,34 0,1,1-46,0z" fill="#069"/>
  <path d="M46,43v35a28,28 0,0,1-14-49zM54,43v35a28,28 0,0,0 14-49z" fill="#396"/>
  <circle r="15" cx="50" cy="18" fill="#900"/>
</svg>
```

real image

[image]

output image from this code above

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really dont know why this is happening with this library, since there is no answer i have changed the SVGSalamendar to Batik Library and if someone needs, this is the working code for it

**Maven Dependencies**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-svggen</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/batik/batik-transcoder -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
  <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
   <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/batik/batik-rasterizer -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
  <artifactId>batik-rasterizer</artifactId>
  <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Java code to reflect same result as above :

```
private static Image createSVGImage(PdfWriter pdfWriter, String imageEntry) throws BadElementException, IOException {
        Image image = null;
        final BufferedImage[] imagePointer = new BufferedImage[1];

        PdfContentByte pdfCB = new PdfContentByte(pdfWriter);   

         try {

                TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(new FileInputStream(imageEntry));

                ImageTranscoder t = new ImageTranscoder() {

                    @Override
                    public BufferedImage createImage(int w, int h) {
                        return new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void writeImage(BufferedImage img, TranscoderOutput output) throws TranscoderException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         imagePointer[0] = img;

                    }
                };
                t.addTranscodingHint(ImageTranscoder.KEY_FORCE_TRANSPARENT_WHITE,
                        Boolean.FALSE);
                t.addTranscodingHint(ImageTranscoder.KEY_BACKGROUND_COLOR, Color.white);
                t.transcode(input, null);
            }
            catch (TranscoderException ex) {
                // Requires Java 6
                ex.printStackTrace();
                throw new IOException("Couldn't convert ");
            }

          image = Image.getInstance(pdfCB, imagePointer[0], 1);     

        return image;
    }
```